ShardingSphere disable SingleTableSQLRouter
I find that the default flow to deal with a dml sql includes ShardingSQLRouter and SingleTableSQLRouter. The SingleTableSQLRouter will find the datasource using the metadata of the table. I want to disable the usage of the SingleTableSQLRouter and force using sharding rules for each sql. If the table is not configured in the sharding rules, instead of using the SingleTableSQLRouter to find a potential datasource, what I want is an error notifying myself that a sharding rule is missing for this table.
The maven setting for sharding-sphere is as following.
<dependency>      
     <groupId>org.apache.shardingsphere</groupId>
     <artifactId>shardingsphere-jdbc-core</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>

My database is MySQL.
If no sharding rule is configured for a specific table, I hope the sharding sphere won't match any datasource for me and throw an exception warning that the sharding rule for this table is missing.
